# Uploading PyPi Package error

Tags: python, package, pypi

I am trying to upload a pypi package, first i found out that setup_tools was really old, so that is now updated, though i still get the same error, and google is not really helping me much on this subject.

```
python setup.py sdist upload -r pypitest
/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'include_package_data'
  warnings.warn(msg)
/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'
  warnings.warn(msg)
/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running sdist
running check
warning: sdist: manifest template 'MANIFEST.in' does not exist (using default file list)

warning: sdist: standard file not found: should have one of README, README.txt

writing manifest file 'MANIFEST'
creating arcsightrest-1.0
making hard links in arcsightrest-1.0...
hard linking arcsightrest.py -> arcsightrest-1.0
hard linking setup.cfg -> arcsightrest-1.0
hard linking setup.py -> arcsightrest-1.0
Creating tar archive
removing 'arcsightrest-1.0' (and everything under it)
running upload
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    'python-dateutil',
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/command/upload.py", line 60, in run
    self.upload_file(command, pyversion, filename)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/command/upload.py", line 70, in upload_file
    raise AssertionError("unsupported schema " + schema)
AssertionError: unsupported schema
```

If i try to run register it works just fine:

```
python setup.py register -r test
/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'include_package_data'
  warnings.warn(msg)
/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'
  warnings.warn(msg)
/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running register
running check
Registering arcsightrest to https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (200): OK
```

Anyone had this problem before?

.pypirc file is also available, and works just fine with register.

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi
    test

[pypi]
repository: https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username: ****
password: ****

[test]
repository: https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
username: ****
password: ****
```

Setup.py file (UPDATED with the import mentioned in the answer):

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='arcsightrest',
    version='1.0',
    description='Python library to connect to the HP Arcsight Logger REST API',
    author='***',
    license='MIT',
    author_email='***',
    url='****',
    download_url='****',
    keywords=['arcsight', 'logger', 'rest'],
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=True,
    py_modules=['arcsightrest'],
    install_requires=[
        'pytz',
        'untangle',
        'requests',
        'python-dateutil',
    ],
)
```

**UPDATE:**
Trying to change the setup.py got me a bit closer, for some reason it asks for my password now, but the end result is still the same error:

```
python setup.py sdist upload -r pypitest
running sdist
running egg_info
writing requirements to arcsightrest.egg-info/requires.txt
writing arcsightrest.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to arcsightrest.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to arcsightrest.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'arcsightrest.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'arcsightrest.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
warning: sdist: standard file not found: should have one of README, README.rst, README.txt

running check
creating arcsightrest-1.0
creating arcsightrest-1.0/arcsightrest.egg-info
copying files to arcsightrest-1.0...
copying arcsightrest.py -> arcsightrest-1.0
copying setup.cfg -> arcsightrest-1.0
copying setup.py -> arcsightrest-1.0
copying arcsightrest.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> arcsightrest-1.0/arcsightrest.egg-info
copying arcsightrest.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> arcsightrest-1.0/arcsightrest.egg-info
copying arcsightrest.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> arcsightrest-1.0/arcsightrest.egg-info
copying arcsightrest.egg-info/requires.txt -> arcsightrest-1.0/arcsightrest.egg-info
copying arcsightrest.egg-info/top_level.txt -> arcsightrest-1.0/arcsightrest.egg-info
copying arcsightrest.egg-info/zip-safe -> arcsightrest-1.0/arcsightrest.egg-info
Writing arcsightrest-1.0/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'arcsightrest-1.0' (and everything under it)
running upload
Password:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    'python-dateutil',
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/command/upload.py", line 60, in run
    self.upload_file(command, pyversion, filename)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/command/upload.py", line 70, in upload_file
    raise AssertionError("unsupported schema " + schema)
AssertionError: unsupported schema
```

Setuptools version:

```
setuptools 28.8.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (Python 2.7)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *Unsupported schema* refers to the [*URL scheme*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) of the repository URL; it has to be one of `http` or `https`.

The error happens because `-r` takes an *URL* to the repository, or an exact name that is specified in `.pypirc`:

```
% python setup.py upload --help
...
Options for 'upload' command:
  --repository (-r)  url of repository [default:
                     https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/]
```

Your `.pypirc` specifies `test` yet you're trying `pypitest`.

---

Some of these options are not recognized by `distutils.core.setup` (as evidenced by the `UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: ...`); therefore you should use `setuptools.setup` instead:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    ...
)
```

(and make sure that `setuptools` is up-to-date).

Comment: I have added more information, and the output after the changes. Register still works.. only upload asks for password as well.

Comment: Correct answer, the first problem was the old setuptools, the other was the repo name was wrong

Comment: Thanks - this just saved my bacon (and sanity!)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. Then, I realize that the error should print the schema. But my error was like this

```
...
    raise AssertionError("unsupported schema " + schema)
AssertionError: unsupported schema
```

Note that `schema` is an empty string. So, in my point of view, the schema hasn't been found. I tried many things, but only changing the permission of `.pypirc` file works. I just did

```
$ sudo chmod 777 ~/.pypirc
```